# Maximums within Portions of a Matrix in R

Tags: r, loops, matrix

I have the following matrix:

```
distances   nodes
1  0.7086445 1, 2, 3
2  0.6975919 1, 2, 4
3  0.7123708 1, 3, 4
4  0.6778857 2, 1, 3
5  0.6886261 2, 1, 4
6  0.6922472 2, 3, 4
7  0.7041895 3, 1, 2
8  0.7005059 3, 1, 4
9  0.6895803 3, 2, 4
10 0.8142009 4, 1, 2
11 0.7973094 4, 1, 3
12 0.8099419 4, 2, 3
```

For each portion of the matrix where the first element of `nodes` is the same value (i.e. each chunk of three rows), I would like to do the following: if EACH of the three values in `distances` for that chunk are greater than all the other distances in the matrix outside of the chunk, then identify the chunk.

For example, here rows 10, 11, and 12 all have `distances` greater than all the other `distances` in the part of the matrix that does not include 10, 11, and 12, and I would like to identify this chunk (where `nodes` starts with 4).

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there's a more elegant solution, but here's how I did it:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data_frame(
  distances = c(0.7086445, 0.6975919, 0.7123708, 0.6778857, 0.6886261, 0.6922472,
                0.7041895, 0.7005059, 0.6895803, 0.8142009, 0.7973094, 0.8099419),
  node1 = c(1,1,1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4),
  node2 = c(2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2),
  node3 = c(3, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 2, 4, 4, 2, 3, 3)
)

get_max <- function(df, node) {
  maxes <- df %>%
    filter(node1 != node)
  return(max(maxes$distances))
}

tbl <- df %>%
  group_by(node1) %>%
  summarize(min = min(distances)) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(ex_max = get_max(df, node1)) %>%
  filter(min > ex_max)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first count the number of distances a certain distance is greater than. eg distance number ten is larger or equal to 12 distances, ie it is the maximum `with(dat,rowSums(outer(distances,distances,">=")))` or `with(dat,match(distances,sort(distances)))`, then group them by the first value of `nodes` and determine whether all the values in the chunk when sorted, have a difference of 1, ie they follow one another, ie, they are from the same chunck, and also if the chunk contains the maximum value,ie it is greater than all the rest.

```
dat$ind=sub("(\\d).*","\\1",dat$nodes)


merge(subset(stack(with(dat,by(match(distances,sort(distances)),ind,
   function(x) all(diff(sort(x))==1)&any(x==nrow(dat))))),values),dat,by="ind")
 ind values distances   nodes
1   4   TRUE 0.8142009 4, 1, 2
2   4   TRUE 0.7973094 4, 1, 3
3   4   TRUE 0.8099419 4, 2, 3
```